# I keep on getting a type error

Tags: python, class

Well I'm teaching myself about python classes and when I run my code I get the following error:

```
    class Critter(object):
        """A virtual pet"""
            def _init_(self, name, mood):
                print("A new critter has been born!!!!!")
                self.name = name
                self.__mood = mood 

           def talk(self):
           print("\n Im",self.name)
           print("Right now I feel",self._mood)

           def _private_method(self):
               print("this is a private method")

           def public(self):
               print("This is a public method. ")
               self._private_method( )

crit = Critter(name = "Poochie", mood = "happy")
crit.talk( )crit.public_method( )

input("Press enter to leave")
```

I receive the error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/calebmatthias/Document/workspace/de.vogella.python.first/practice.py", line   27, in <module>
    crit = Critter(name = "Poochie", mood = "happy")
TypeError: object.__new__() takes no parameters
```

Comment: For future reference when you do go to [SO], make sure you have your python code correctly indented as it is in your source. You can't expect anyone to help you if the code you show us does not have the same indentation.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend that you more carefully format your submissions.  Python is really picky about indentation -- read [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for a good intro on how to properly format Python code.

The problem is that you spelled `__init__` wrong.  You have `_init_` which is just another method to Python.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the following corrected code runs fine (_init_ changed to __init__; _mood changed to __mood; public_method changed to public; indentation corrected):

```
class Critter(object):
    """A virtual pet"""
    def __init__(self, name, mood):
        print("A new critter has been born!!!!!")
        self.name = name
        self.__mood = mood 

    def talk(self):
        print("\n Im",self.name)
        print("Right now I feel",self.__mood)

    def _private_method(self):
        print("this is a private method")

    def public(self):
        print("This is a public method. ")
        self._private_method( )

crit = Critter(name="Poochie", mood="happy")
crit.talk()
crit.public()

input("Press enter to leave")
```

...and the output:

```
A new critter has been born!!!!!

 Im Poochie
Right now I feel happy
This is a public method. 
this is a private method
Press enter to leave
```